# Angular 2 + Vert.x: send-receive body of HTTP requests

Tags: java, angular, typescript, http-post, vert.x

I made a simple REST application using the Vert.x framework server side and Angular 2 (v6.0.9) client side. What I want to do is make the server display the received data. However I can not figure out how to retrieve the HTTP request body: both `routingContext.getBodyAsString()` and `routingContext.getBodyAsJson()` returns null. As a temporary solution, I managed to display all the sent data through the path parameters using `getParam("data")` method. What am I doing wrong?

Server code

```
package test.post;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.core.json.Json;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.CorsHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;

public class Server extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        Set<String> allowedHeaders = new HashSet<>();
        allowedHeaders.add("x-requested-with");
        allowedHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        allowedHeaders.add("origin");
        allowedHeaders.add("Content-Type");
        allowedHeaders.add("accept");
        allowedHeaders.add("X-PINGARUNER");

        Set<HttpMethod> allowedMethods = new HashSet<>();
        allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.GET);
        allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.POST);
        allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
        allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.DELETE);
        allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.PATCH);
        allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.PUT);

        router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("*").allowedHeaders(allowedHeaders).allowedMethods(allowedMethods));

        router.post("/test/post/handler/:data").handler(this::receive);

        // Serve the static pages
        router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
        System.out.println("Service running");
    }

    private void receive(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        System.out.println("received post request");
        System.out.println(routingContext.getBodyAsString());
        System.out.println(routingContext.getBodyAsJson());
        System.out.println(routingContext.request().getParam("data"));
        routingContext.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").end(Json.encodePrettily("ok"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        Server service = new Server();
        vertx.deployVerticle(service);
    }
}
```

Client app.component.ts code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestService } from './request.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h2>Click to send post request</h2>
    <button type="submit" (click)=makePostRequest()>Send Post Request</button>
    `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private requestService: RequestService) { }

  makePostRequest() {
    this.requestService.sendRequest().subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
}
```

Client request.service.ts code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class User {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  address: string;
  username: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendRequest(): Observable<any> {
    let user = new User();
    user.username = 'Admin';
    user.email = 'admin@gmail.com';
    user.password = 'admin';
    user.address = 'somewhere';

    console.log(user);

    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/post/handler/' + JSON.stringify(user);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options: { headers, responseType: 'json' };
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user), options).pipe(
      tap(response => console.log(response))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable body handler in order to read request body, e.g:

```
router.route("/test/post*").handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.post("/test/post/handler/:data").handler(this::receive);
```

or enable it globally:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create())
```

Comment: How to do this in Quarkus?